# Add rows (duplicate them) based on presence of symbol in string within cell of df

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

at the beginning I'd like to say that I didin'd find any simillar question to this, if they exist - my fault, mark this question as a duplicate.

**What do I have? - Fictional Data, reproducible set**

```
signal1 <- c(rep(1:6))
signal2 <- c(rep(7:12))
signal3 <- c(rep(13:18))
signal4 <- c(rep(19:24))
tag <- c('str1','str2','str3','str4','str5','str6')
gene <- c('ABC','ABC','ABC;DEF','ABC;DEF','DEF','DEF')
df <- data.frame(signal1,signal2,signal3,signal4,some_coulmn,gene)
df
signal1 signal2 signal3 signal4 tag       gene
1       7       13      19      str1      ABC
2       8       14      20      str2      ABC
3       9       15      21      str3      ABC;DEF
4       10      16      22      str4      ABC;DEF
5       11      17      23      str5      DEF
6       12      18      24      str6      DEF
```

**What I want to get?**

**First of all, df duplicate rows where semicolon is present in rows, column `gene`.**

```
signal1 signal2 signal3 signal4 tag     gene
1       7       13      19      str1    ABC
2       8       14      20      str2    ABC
3       9       15      21      str3    ABC;DEF
3       9       15      21      str3    ABC;DEF
4       10      16      22      str4    ABC;DEF
4       10      16      22      str4    ABC;DEF
5       11      17      23      str5    DEF
6       12      18      24      str6    DEF
```

The order of rows after duplication isn't important. They can be added at the end of df.

**In addition to this - removal of unnecessary genes in rows:**

As you see I'd like to have unambiguous groups of genes, without any overlaps. If tag is present in **two or more genes** additional row for each gene is needed!

```
signal1 signal2 signal3 signal4 tag     gene
1       7       13      19      str1    ABC
2       8       14      20      str2    ABC
3       9       15      21      str3    ABC
3       9       15      21      str3    DEF
4       10      16      22      str4    ABC
4       10      16      22      str4    DEF
5       11      17      23      str5    DEF
6       12      18      24      str6    DEF
```

Here's my attempt, unfortunately doesn't work properly. What is more it works only with two genes separated by semicolon. Won't work in case of

```
GENE1;GENE2;GENE3
```

or more

```
library(stringr)
df_tmp <- df
sapply(1:nrow(df_tmp), function(x) ifelse(str_detect(as.character(df_tmp[x,22]), ';'), df <- rbind(df_tmp, df_tmp[x,22]), df_tmp[x,22]))
```

Could you give me a hint how to do this...

Comment: `str_detect` only detects if any `";"` is in the string. You can try and use `strsplit()` which will split the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` and `tidyr::unnest`:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(gene = strsplit(as.character(gene), ";")) %>%
    unnest()
#  signal1 signal2 signal3 signal4  tag gene
#1       1       7      13      19 str1  ABC
#2       2       8      14      20 str2  ABC
#3       3       9      15      21 str3  ABC
#4       3       9      15      21 str3  DEF
#5       4      10      16      22 str4  ABC
#6       4      10      16      22 str4  DEF
#7       5      11      17      23 str5  DEF
#8       6      12      18      24 str6  DEF
```

Explanation: `strsplit` splits column `gene` entries based on `";"` and stores the entries in a `list`, which we then expand using `tidyr::unnest`.

---

### Update

Example for `>2` semicolon-separated entries:

```
df <- structure(list(signal1 = 1:6, signal2 = 7:12, signal3 = 13:18,
    signal4 = 19:24, tag = structure(1:6, .Label = c("str1",
    "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"), class = "factor"),
    gene = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("ABC",
    "ABC;DEF", "DEF", "DEF;GHI;JKL"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("signal1",
"signal2", "signal3", "signal4", "tag", "gene"), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = "data.frame");
df;
#  signal1 signal2 signal3 signal4  tag        gene
#1       1       7      13      19 str1         ABC
#2       2       8      14      20 str2         ABC
#3       3       9      15      21 str3     ABC;DEF
#4       4      10      16      22 str4     ABC;DEF
#5       5      11      17      23 str5         DEF
#6       6      12      18      24 str6 DEF;GHI;JKL


library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(gene = strsplit(as.character(gene), ";")) %>%
    unnest()
#   signal1 signal2 signal3 signal4  tag gene
#1        1       7      13      19 str1  ABC
#2        2       8      14      20 str2  ABC
#3        3       9      15      21 str3  ABC
#4        3       9      15      21 str3  DEF
#5        4      10      16      22 str4  ABC
#6        4      10      16      22 str4  DEF
#7        5      11      17      23 str5  DEF
#8        6      12      18      24 str6  DEF
#9        6      12      18      24 str6  GHI
#10       6      12      18      24 str6  JKL
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! Will it work when we have 3 or more genes separated with semicolons?

Comment: @Adamm Yes, should work for any number of genes, as long as they are semicolon separated.

Answer (score 2):

A base R way might be to split the column, create an index based on the lengths of each element, subset, and update

```
splt = strsplit(gene, ";")
idx = rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(splt))
df = df[idx,]
df$gene = unlist(splt)
rownames(df) = NULL                   # clean up duplicated row names
```